# Swift -Position new UIWIndow in center of Screen

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect, uiwindow, cgpoint

The user taps a cell, I get the touchLocation, create and then animate a new UIWindow to the center of the screen. The problem is when the new window (purple) appears on screen instead of its center being in the center of the screen, its x,y coordinate starts at the center of the screen.

I get this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

```
// the collectionView is dimmed black, that's why the background color is dark
guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }

let startingRect = CGRect(x: userTouchPointX, y: userTouchPointY, width: 10, height: 10)

let newWindow = UIWindow(frame: startingRect)
newWindow.backgroundColor = .clear
newWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.normal
newWindow.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PurpleVC())
newWindow.isHidden = false
newWindow.makeKey()

let endingCenterX = keyWindow.screen.bounds.midX // I also tried keyWindow.frame.width / 2 and also UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
let endingCenterY = keyWindow.screen.bounds.midY // I also tried keyWindow.frame.height / 2 and also UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
let endingWidth = keyWindow.frame.width
let endingHeight: CGFloat = 200

let endingCenter = CGPoint(x: endingCenterX, y: endingCenterY)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {

    newWindow.center = endingCenter
    newWindow.frame.size.width = endingWidth
    newWindow.frame.size.height = endingHeight
}) { (_) in

    newWindow.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your center After setting the frame of the window will solve your issue ... hopefully it will help

```
// newWindow.center = endingCenter remove from here
    newWindow.frame.size.width = endingWidth
    newWindow.frame.size.height = endingHeight
    newWindow.center = endingCenter // add it here
```

Comment: its not completion handler sir

Comment: in UIView.animate you just need to update `layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: whats keyWindow center ?

Comment: dont call layoutifneeded on completion

Comment: keywindow is the original window. I already tried calling newWindow.layoutIfNeeded() inside the callback, the same problem occurs. I just added your exact code exactly like you wrote it. Same problem occurs. Thanks for trying

Comment: where do you see keyWindow center at? I didn't write that anywhere

Comment: call center after setting frame will resolve the issue

Comment: @LanceSamaria take your time sir

Comment: What worked was adding the frame after setting the width and height. Change your answer to just say that and I will accept it. Btw I call layoutIfNeeded() in the compeltionHandler. I just upvoted your comment. Change your answer to match your comment and I will accept it. I can't accept the answer now because it has view.addSubView in it and that's not in my question

Comment: thanks for the help. It's just a recommndedation but if you have the time add the code. It helps other users. Happy coding!!!

Comment: so combo of both is perfect for any answer that solves someones issue ... its kind of appreciation for others time ...